# Fetch Facebook notifications API 3.0

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an app for Android and I need to be able to periodically fetch how many unread notifications a user has and display this in my app.

I believe this is not straight forward in the 3.0 API.

Can somebody please explain the best method for this?

I am using this code:

```
Request notificationsRequest = Request.newGraphPathRequest(
        Session.getActiveSession(), "/me/notifications",
        new Request.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                GraphObject object = response.getGraphObject();
                if (object != null) {
                    notifications = object.getProperty("data")
                            .toString();
                } else {
                    notifications = "Notifications returns null";
                }
            }
        });
```

But it's returning `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include "include_read" and "true". 
You can do it like this:

```
if (object != null) {

    try {

    JSONObject jsonObject = object.getInnerJSONObject().getJSONObject("summary");
    int notificationsUnread = jsonObject.getInt("unseen_count");

    Log.i("FB notificationsSummary", jsonObject + "");

    } catch (JSONException e) {             
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();                        
    }


    Bundle notificationParams = new Bundle();
    notificationParams.putString("include_read", "true");
    yourRequest.setParameters(notificationParams);

    yourRequest.execute();
}
```